# Books for starting with theory of languages

Tags: discussion, support, computational-linguistics

I have computer science background and I am looking for some NLP algorithms for stemming, POS tagging etc. The language under consideration is "**agglutinative and inflectional**". Since from CS background, I am finding it difficult to understand these terms. It would be helpful, if you could give me some introductory books dealing with these.

Comment: Any introduction to linguistics would cover basic terms like that. Or you might as well just read Wikipedia. For topics like that it will be very good.